# Function to use "-" as text

Tags: r, subset, data-cleaning

I'm having a problem in R.

I have some data where I have different regions. Below is an example and it's actual names not values.

```
D1$Regions = c(Ab, Ba, Da-Cd, Db-a, Da-Aa)
```

If I only want to use the region Da-Cd and trying to select that one only I get an error.

```
D-C<-D1[D1$Regions =="Da-Cd",]
```

I get following this error:

```
Error in D - C <- D1[D1$Region == "Da-Cd", ] : 
  object 'Da' not found
```

I assume it's because it's trying to subtract C from D, but in this case the actual name of the region is D-C. What can I do to only select that region?
Can I do it without having to rename the region?

In my data I have several regions with a "-" between letters. It'll be fine if the "-" is removed for all the different regions.

I have tried to use D1$Region as character and as factor but that doesn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible example. Unless you have objects called e.g. `Da-Cd`, the first line isn't valid R syntax; either way, it's unclear exactly what you're working with

Answer (score 2):

`-` shouldn't be used in a name since it is reserved for the subtraction operator; it is *reserved/illegal*. But you could get around it by surrounding the name with illegal symbols with  ``` `` ```, although in some (all?) contexts the more familiar `""` will suffice.

```
`D-C` <- D1[D1$Regions =="Da-Cd",]
```

Answer (score 1):

R reads `Da-Cd` as `Da` minus `Cd`. I'd suggest to use characters as names for regions, i.e. `c("Ab", "Ba", "Da-Cd", "Db-a", "Da-Aa")`